# Parsing an xl field into first name, last name and phone number

Tags: excel, vba

In xl, I have a field that is lastname, firstname phone number.  I need to parse the string into 3 fields: LastName; FirstName; and PhoneNumber.  The name fields are separated by a comma.  I can parse the names, but to complicate things, the phone number sometimes is 8 characters (3 + a dash + 3) (Koshevoy, Oleg 345-5387), and sometimes it is 12 characters (3 + 1 dash + 3 + 1 dash + 4)(Cooke, Lisa 239-980-6688).  IF the field is 8 characters, I need to prepend the 941 area code before it & a "-".

The End result should look like "Robert" "Smith" "941-525-2752" across three columns.  Can you help?

Comment: If every single phone number contains zero spaces then using [InstrRev](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251545.aspx) to find the last space character in the string will get you most of the way there

Answer (score 0):

Try this with the idea of barrowc:

```
Sub test()
i = 1
While Not IsEmpty(Cells(i, 1)) 'search until column A is not empty
lastblank = InStrRev(Cells(i, 1), " ", , vbTextCompare) 'find the last blank
phone = Mid(Cells(i, 1), lastblank + 1, 12) 'take the text (e.g. 12) after the last blank (without the blank)
If Len(phone) = 8 Then
phone = "941-" + phone 'add if phone length = 8
End If
ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2).Value = phone 'copy to column B
i = i + 1
Wend
End Sub
```